# Error when run Monkeyrunner

Tags: android, batch-file, monkeyrunner

> ..............AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>monkeyrunner.bat

1. once I run the above in CMD, it gives the output as 
   SWT folder `'..\framework\x86_64'` does not exist.
2. Then I set the path as follows;
   `..............AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>set` `ANDROID_SWT=C:\Users\Dilusha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\x86_64`

3.Then again I ran the following command .

```
..............AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>monkeyrunner.bat
```

4.I got following error;

> Error: Unable to access jarfile
>   ..\framework\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar

I have stuck on this step and could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Just Edit the monkeyrunner.bat file in Notepad

You need to comment:

```
for /f %%a in ("%APP_HOME%\lib\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar") do set jarfile=%%~nxa
```

and add:

```
set jarfile=..\lib\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

```
for /f %%a in ("%APP_HOME%\lib\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar") do set jarfile=%%~nxa
```

with:

```
set jarfile=..\lib\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
set frameworkdir=lib
```

to:

```
if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
set frameworkdir=..\lib
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation of how this will solve OPs problem?